# Can 【～たら】 be a short form of 【～てから】?

Tags: usage, contractions

I picked up a bad habit of using ～たら (a form of conditional) when I mean ～てから (once something happens, something else will happen) from a friend many years back while learning Japanese.

In the years since, I learned the difference and felt bad when I still used たら out of habit. But, I was just thinking, since there are spoken short forms of various ～て forms (～ておく　→　～とく、～ている → ～てる) and I can't help but wonder if this is another case like that.

In short, is ～たら　one of the spoken contractions of ～てから?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not the first to say "No", but I want to actually show where ～たら comes from, if it's not an abbreviated form of ～てから. Consider it a proof of sorts. :)

The Classical Japanese of early Heian period had a form called ～たり form, which was used for several jobs that today are fulfilled by the ～た, ～て and (the modern) ～たり forms. This form was attached to the *renyōkei* (連用形), which is the verb stem that ends in I for Godan verbs (this is the stem to which you attach the ～ます or ～たい endings).

The ~たり form was later shortened to ~た in speech and became the past form we all known and love today, but before that, it was actually used to build a few other forms. Now, the ～たり form was actually creating a new verb (just like adding the potential, passive or causative endings to a verb today create a new verb), so it had it's own stem to which other endings could be attached. One of them was the old hypothetical ending ～ば (actually, the famous particle は which became ば after the verb). ば was attached to the *mizenkei* (未然形),  which is the verb stem that ends in A for Godan verbs (this is the stem to which you attach the ～ない ending used for negation). Since, the mizenkei of ～たり was naturally ～たら, the whole thing together was ～たらば, which at sometime became a very common complex form for conditionals. e.g. (I invented this up myself, so it's probably not quite authentic):

> 書きたらば、死ぬ。    If you write, you die.

In modern Japanese, the classical ～ば form became the modern conditional ～ば which is now attached to the E stem (已然形 *izenkei*), and is much better known as the *-eba* conditional ending. But what happened to the complex ～たらば～ form? It was shortened to ~たら, but also started using the different base that ～て and ～た forms (the later also a shortened form of ～たり) were using. In Ichidan verbs (such as 見る or 食べる) this is still the same as good old *renyōkei*, but in godan verb, a few changes occured:

- wakar**i** + tara -> waka**r** + tara -> waka**t** + **t**ara -> waka**tt**ara
- kak**i** + tara -> ka**i** + tara -> ka**it**ara
- oyog**i** + tara -> oyo**i** + (voice) + tara -> oyo**i** + **d**ara -> oyo**id**ara
- mat**i** + tara -> ma**t** + **t**ara -> ma**tt**ara

There are more, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: oh, very nice answer. Can you also tell me where ～てから comes from for contrast?

Comment: @Boaz: Two things: 1. Do you teach a class on classical Japanese? 2. If so, where can I sign up?

Comment: @Derek: I wish. I have hard time reading Classical Japanese myself, and I remember only a little bit of the grammar. :( But being a linguist has its perks: I check some books written in linguistic mumbo-jumbo (which turns out to be really useful as a shortcut) and compare everything. In this case I remembered something about たら coming from たらば, but I didn't know all these details before checking the books.

Comment: @Jeshi: I think the origin of ～てから is much simpler. In essence, this is just the regular te-form + the directional particle から. The te-form itself exists, as far as I know, back in Old Japanese as a particle (て）which is joined to the renyōkei.

Comment: What do you mean by “E stem (以前系 izenkei)”?  In my knowledge of the modern Japanese grammar, the forms before ば is called 仮定形 (かていけい) (but I am not sure how foreign learners usually learn verb forms).  The Classical Japanese has a verb form called 已然形 (いぜんけい), but its use is different.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Yeah, it's also called 仮定形, and that's probably a more accurate term for what we're having today, but both are used. And I'm sorry for my regularily misformed kanji. I was writing them on a low resolution screen where you can't really read anything, so I sometimes don't notice IME misfires. :(

Comment: `The te-form itself exists, as far as I know, back in Old Japanese as a particle (て）which is joined to the renyōkei.` ...to [onbinkei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_conjugation#Verb_bases) maybe? You say so yourself in the answer that it's not exactly renyōkei ("but in godan verb, a few changes occured"). Or you mean that in Old Japanese て was attached to renyōkei even for godan verbs?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: No.

～ておく and ～ている can become ～とく and ～てる because they have consecutive vowels, which are easily slurred/elided, but to get ～てから to become ～たら, you'd have to drop a consonant, which I don't believe ever happens in Japanese (but I would welcome a correction here). In addition, the ～たら and ～てから forms have different functions grammatically, so you can't simply interchange them without considering the context and the rest of the sentence.

Comment: I had a feeling that would be the case. Good point about removing the consonant... I'll see if I can't think of any counter examples. :)

Comment: As a side note, there is a ~ったら ending, used, for example, after a person's name. It carries a different meaning that indicates the user's exasperation or annoyance with the person, but has nothing to do with either ~たら or ~てから. But, you probably know this. :)

Comment: Ah, you are right, I was thinking ～たら, not ったら

Comment: @Jeshii: I figured you meant the verb conjugation, but in your defense, there are many verbs with ～たら forms that end in ～ったら.

Comment: Actually consonant-dropping happened quite a lot in Japanese, but it usually was with "weak" vowels such as /u/ and /i/ and not with /a/. One prominent case is the き that used to be the attributive (rentaikei) ending of adjectives in classical Japanese and became just い in the modern language. So instead of 白き花 we now say 白いはな. Anyway, in this case you are correct: ~たら is note a shortened form of ～てから.

Comment: Dropping a consonant happens a lot, especially in casual speech: だっただろう->だったろう, わからない->わかんない, あたたかい->あったかい, etc.

Comment: @Amanda: You're absolutely right. Curiously, looking at that list, the condensed syllables come from the same vowel row. Are there any such contractions that go across vowel rows?

Comment: Dropping consonsants happens in one of the most common words in the language: おはよう. The origin is basically お+はやく -> おはやう -> おはよう. ありがとう was formed by the same process. Adverbs are still formed this way today in Kansai-ben, too.

Answer (score 2):

I would say No.

> たら has sense of "if ... then ...."
>
> てから "... then ..."

Following with たら　is ok

> 雨が降っ**たら**出かけないことにする。If it rains, I won't go outside.

but following with てから　is kinda strange.

> 雨が降っ**てから**出かけないことにする　After it rains, I won't go outside.